# How to write common unit test code for all the popular CMS

Tags: phpunit

I have a plugin made for WP, Drupal, SMF, WP etc and now i want to write unit test for them. So is there any way to write common unit test code for them or , maybe, just the base code, i don't want to write unit test for each plugin separately.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your plugin actually does, the answer might be a little bit meta.

You should use [**polymorphism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29):

- Create an [`interface`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) which will contain all the prototypes of the methods used for testing functionality (ie, if your plugin formats a post, you will have a method in that interface called `format_post()` )
- for each of the CRMs, create a class that will implement that interface
- in your file which executes the tests, create an instance for each of the CRM testing classes (which implement the interface that defines `format_post()` ) and call `format_post()` on them

Comment: My plugin is a basic chat. I only want to test the settings array and the server response for auth, which is common in all the plugins.

Comment: you could then use a `base class` to contain the common functionality instead of an `interface` and your child classes to `extend` that one. The idea is the same - the parent class will guarantee the fact that the child classes contain the code that you call polymorphically (`format_post()` in my example, or `test_settings_array()` in your specific case)

Comment: Okay. Also is there any way to create an object of phpunit class and use it inside my code, like i have a function saveSettings() where settings[] is generated and sent to server via post so can it be like this
`$settings = ['setting1'=>'a', 'setting2'=>'b']; $o->testSettingsArray($settings); saveSettingsOnServer($settings);`
where $o is an object of phpunit class.